# What would be the execution time for the following algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The following code returns all the prime factors of the given number n.

> Approach behind the algorithm:

Iterate over the numbers (i.e. >=2) till n/i to get the prime factors.

The internal loop simply reduces the size of the number by dividing it with the current prime number and if the same prime number appears more than once it will keep on dividing.

The if statement would add the last & the highest prime number for n > 2 since n would have been reduced to that value by that time.

```
static List<Integer> getAllPrimes(int n){
            List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 2 ; i <= n/i ; ++i){ 
                while(n % i == 0){ 
                    factors.add(i); //LINE 1
                    n/=i;
                }
            }
            if(n > 2){factors.add(n);} 
            return factors;
}
```

How the running time would be determined for this algorithm? Since Each time the inner loop is iterated it decreases the size with some constant value say n/2,n/3.... etc based on the index i if it's a prime number.

Comment: This is actually standard algorithm for prime factorization of a number having worst case complexity as `O(sqrt(n))` and worst case is any prime number as `n`. You can go through this [**article**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/).

Comment: Can you please prove how in worst case Line 1 would be executed sqrt(n) times either using mathematics or simple test cases. I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Well in worst case, `n` doesn't get decreased in inner while loop. So `n` remains same as initial value in the whole execution of `for` loop. `For` loop takes `O(sqrt(n))` time if `n` is same as initial value. Then at last in `if(n>2)` statement, `n` will be added to the list. This way this takes `O(sqrt(n))` in worst case. Worst case inputs are prime numbers (Take 11 as an example and find how much time the for loop runs).

Comment: @SanketMakani ... Thanks! Great! +1 , Unfortunately I can't accept comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When analyzing an algorithm like this, it's often helpful to clarify whether you're looking for a best-case, average-case, or worst-case analysis, since the answer might differ in each case.

Let's start with a worst-case analysis. What would have to happen to keep this algorithm running as long as possible? Well, if we never divide out any prime factors, then the outer loop will run as many times as possible. Specifically, it'll run Θ(√n) times. This only happens if the number in question is prime, and so we can say that the worst case occurs on prime number inputs, where the runtime is Θ(√n).

What about the best case? Well, this algorithm is going to terminate either when i gets too large for n or n gets too small for i. It's significantly faster to drop n than to increase i because n drops geometrically while i increases arithmetically. An ideal case would be an input that drops as fast as possible, which happens if you provide it an input that only has tiny small factors (these are called smooth numbers). In the ideal case, you'll get a perfect power of two, and in that case the algorithm cuts n in half repeatedly until it drops to 1. That's the hallmark of logarithmic behavior, so in the best case the runtime is Θ(log n).

Comment: Thanks for best case analysis too! :)